# Global List into a MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My problem is that I need to load a big list of strings into the application , when application starts and I need to be able to access it into all view and controllers, like a global list.
I am using MVC and repository.
So the list is provided by a repository method from database.
If i put is into global.asax I can have access to repository interface.
Any ideas?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why can't you just instantiate an instance of your repository in the controllers and pull the list from the database when you need it? Global variables/objects are usually a bad practice and are not actually necessary in most cases where developers think of using them.

Comment: Just instantiate your repository in controller construction

Comment: Define "big list". How big are we talking here?

Comment: I am not against global variables for static read-only lists but perhaps a better alternative is the System.Web.Cache.  It is advantageous in that you can set a timeout on your list, requiring it to be refreshed every (specified time interval).  You can also flush the cache if you update the list, which will cause it to be reloaded.  You can write a function that returns the cached value if it exists, or fetches the list from the database, caches it, and returns it if it does not exist.

Comment: The list has 500 string elements

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. I found a good  example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033877/caching-data-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the list isn't so big that it's going to eat up all your server memory, you could stick the list in Cache- however I wouldn't do that in your controller. You're better off creating a custom ValueProvider or using you dependency injection framework so you can avoid coupling your Actions to HttpContext. Mocking HttpContext is ugly, and best if it's abstracted away.